# Are .NET WebServices vulnerable to CSRF?

Tags: csrf, .net

While [developing](http://teammentor.github.com) TeamMentor I implemented a number of WebServices (consumed via jQuery) and now on its final push for release I want to double check that they are not vulnerable to CSRF.

There isn't a lot of good information out there and it seems that in .NET, *.asmx are protected by default to CSRF, with a possible exception of an exploit scenario using Flash (to set the cookies)

[updated info]

If you want to take a look at the code, the whole thing is at GitHub, and here is the source code of the version with a test Library (OWASP Top 10):  https://github.com/TeamMentor-OWASP/Master  (just download the zip file and click on the 'Start webserver.bat' to have a locally running copy)

If you just want to take a look at it, check out this test server: 
http://50.18.82.146:8081 for the main GUI and 
http://50.18.82.146:8081/aspx_pages/tm_webservices.asmx for the webservices
In terms of CSRF for ASMX, my current understanding comes mainly from this Scott Guthrie article http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/04/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks.aspx (also referenced here AJAX Hacker Attacks - Cross Site Request Forgery )

Those articles imply that asmx webservices are not vulnerable to CSRF due to the extra application/json ContentType header.

Answer (score 3):

Without providing more detail about your web services,  I would say **yes** there is a very good chance it is.   However the exploit is probably not what would expect as it is different from your usual HTTP POST/GET CSRF exploit.  In the case of SOAP or other web services the body of the message is XML or some other block of data.  When I write [PoC CSRF exploits](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/7383/) for services like this I am forced to use [ActionScript's request.data](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cfd.html) feature.  It also should be noted that many, but not all of the http request headers can be set and modified with ActionScript.

Comment: Hi Rook, I just updated the original question to add details about where you can get the Source Code of the app (in case you want to take a look at it)

Comment: In terms of the use of ActionScript, that is the only vector that looks like might work, BUT, only if one can set the ContentType to application/json (for example some browsers do allow the manipulation of content type via form submission, BUT only to a set of values (i.e. not to application/json))

Comment: @Dinis Cruz i know for a fact ActionScript works well with json and xml APIs.  Anyway i am not going to look at any of your code.  This isn't free.

Comment: Fair enough, I will :)
Thx for the help